# Hover a parent outside current parent css

Tags: css, hover, parent

I'm trying to make a wrapper that is not part of the current parent change when the link is hovered.

```
<div id="appswrapper">

        <div id="appsspace01"></div>
        <div id="appsspace02"></div>

        <div id="gotomail">
            <a href="#" target="_blank" style="width:305px; height:45px; display:block;"></a>
        </div>

        <div id="labsampler">
            <a href="#" style="width:100px; height:115px; display:block;"></a>
        </div>

        <div id="batchcoder">
            <a href="#" style="width:100px; height:115px; display:block;"></a>
        </div>

        <div id="blank"></div>

        <div id="camviewer">
            <a href="#" style="width:100px; height:115px; display:block;"></a>
        </div>

        <div id="staffpresence">
            <a href="#" style="width:100px; height:115px; display:block;"></a>
        </div>

        <div id="rawmatstock">
            <a href="#" style="width:100px; height:115px; display:block;"></a>
        </div>

        <div id="equipmenttracker">
            <a href="#" style="width:100px; height:115px; display:block;"></a>
        </div>

        <div id="complaintsmanager">
        <a href="#"  style="width:100px; height:115px; display:block;"></a>
        </div>

        <div id="callback">
            <a href="#" style="width:100px; height:115px; display:block;"></a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="wrappertest"></div>
```

The css:

```
#appswrapper{
width: 320px;
height: 500px;
float:left;

}

#appsspace01{
width:10px;
height:500px;
float:left;
}

#appsspace02{
width:310px;
height:5px;
float:left;
}
#gotomail{
width:310px;
height:50px;
float:left;
background:url(../Images/gotomail.png);
}
#gotomail:hover{        
opacity: .4;
width:310px;
height:50px;
float:left;
background:url(../Images/gotomail.png);
-khtml-opacity: 0.4;
-moz-opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}
#labsampler{
width:103px;
height:117px;
float:left;
background:url(../Images/labsampler.png);
}
#labsampler:hover{
width:103px;
height:117px;
float:left;
background-image: url(../Images/labsampler.png);
background: url(../Images/labsampler.png);
opacity: .4;
-khtml-opacity: 0.4;
-moz-opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}
#batchcoder{
width:103px;
height:117px;
float:left;
background:url(../Images/batchcoder.png);
}
#batchcoder:hover{
width:103px;
height:117px;
float:left;
background:url(../Images/batchcoder.png);
-khtml-opacity: 0.4;
-moz-opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
opacity: .4;
}
#blank{
width:104px;
height:117px;
float:left;
background:url(../Images/blank.png);
}
#rawmatstock{
width:104px;
height:117px;
float:left;
background:url(../Images/rawmatstock.png);
}
#rawmatstock:hover{
width:104px;
height:117px;
float:left;
background:url(../Images/rawmatstock.png);
-khtml-opacity: 0.4;
-moz-opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
opacity: .4;
}
#camviewer{
width:103px;
height:117px;
float:left;
background:url(../Images/camviewer.png);
}
#camviewer:hover{
width:103px;
height:117px;
float:left;
background:url(../Images/camviewer.png);
-khtml-opacity: 0.4;
-moz-opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
opacity: .4;
}
#staffpresence{
width:103px;
height:117px;
float:left;
background:url(../Images/staffpresence.png);
}
#staffpresence:hover{
width:103px;
height:117px;
float:left;
background:url(../Images/staffpresence.png);
-khtml-opacity: 0.4;
-moz-opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
opacity: .4;
}
#callback{
width:104px;
height:117px;
float:left;
background:url(../Images/callback.png);
}
#callback:hover{
width:104px;
height:117px;
float:left;
background:url(../Images/callback.png);
-khtml-opacity: 0.4;
-moz-opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
opacity: .4;
}
#complaintsmanager{
width:103px;
height:117px;
float:left;
background:url(../Images/complaintsmanager.png);

}
#complaintsmanager:hover{
width:103px;
height:117px;
float:left;
background:url(../Images/complaintsmanager.png);
opacity: .4;
-khtml-opacity: 0.4;
-moz-opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}
#equipmenttracker{
width:103px;
height:117px;
float:left;
background:url(../Images/equipment-tracker.png);
}
#equipmenttracker:hover{
width:103px;
height:117px;
float:left;
background:url(../Images/equipment-tracker.png);
-khtml-opacity: 0.4;
-moz-opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
opacity: .4;
}
#wrappertest{
width: 620px;
height: 290px;
float:left;
background:url(../Images/testwrapper.png);
}
```

What I tried so far:

```
#callback:hover ~ #wrappertest {
background: url(../Images/rubiolabsampler.png); 
}
#callback:hover + #wrappertest {
background: url(../Images/rubiolabsampler.png);
}

#callback:hover #wrappertest {
background: url(../Images/rubiolabsampler.png);
}
#callback:hover > #wrappertest {
background: url(../Images/rubiolabsampler.png); 
}
```

Can I use the CSS hover system to make the wrappertest change into another background? I can't put them in the same wrapper because it's a complex design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the `<div id="appswrapper">` wrap, you could use

```
#callback:hover + #wrappertest {
  background: url(../Images/rubiolabsampler.png);
}
```

The other solutions you've tried require `#wrappertest` to be inside `#callback`

If you need to keep the markup as it is, I would use jQuery to do this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#callback').hover(function () {
      $('#wrappertest').css('background-image','url("Images/testwrapper.png")');
    },
    function () {
      $('#wrappertest').css('background-image','');
    });
  });
```

Then include jQuery lib in head of your site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i'm not so familiar with jquery, can you help me out to change the background? thx! sry saw it to late, you changed it! thx, i'll check it out right away!

Comment: Yeh, just stick that code in a doc ready tag and include a link to jQuery lib in your <head>

Comment: If you've not used jQuery before, I've edited my answer to give you everything you need. The script code can go anywhere in your page or in a seperte file that you link to.

Comment: If you put the jQuery code in a seperate file, you don't need the <script> tags

Comment: i tried changing the 'background-image' to 'background' since i don't use background-image in my css, but i doesn't seem to work

Comment: thx mate, it works, but i don't get the new image in it, if i hover callback the wrapper background just dissapears

Comment: i tried using the same image so:

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#callback').hover(function () {
      $('#wrappertest').css('background','url(../Images/testwrapper.png)');
    },
    function () {
      $('#wrappertest').css('background','url(../Images/testwrapper.png)');
    });
  });

and it just dissapears the image

Comment: Must be something wrong with the link to your image then. I've made a fiddle here so you can see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ggcj/

Comment: Ah yes, sorry if your CSS file is in a different folder from the HTML, you'll need to change the link. You no longer need to go back 1 directory to find the image. I'll change my code so you can see.